# opencv python documentation

Tags: python, opencv, documentation, code-documentation

Recently, I want to use the `OpenCV` library in `Python`, but the documentation of `Python` binding of `OpenCV` is very unclear and insufficient. I want to ask where to find some detailed documentation of `Python` binding of `OpenCV`. Previously I used `OpenCV` in `C++`, and the documentation is very helpful, more over I can go to the source code of it where I was in doubt. But the source code of `Python` binding doesn't provide much information, I think. For example, it takes me a long time to find out that the `CV_8UC1` flag is in the module `cv2.CV_8UC1`, but the flag `CV_CAP_PROP_FPS` is in the module `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS.`

Comment: >>> help(cv2) #will show you all of it..

Comment: I scraped all the documentation from `help()` that pydoc could find into a webpage [here](https://madebyollin.github.io/opencv-python-docs/), but unfortunately much of it is undocumented (you have to fall back to the C++ documentation).

Answer (score 17):

There doesn't seem to be any nice documentations. Sometimes information is provided about the Python API as part of the normal documentation.

To get started and to get a feel for how the Python OpenCV interface works, have a look at the 
[official Python tutorials](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html).

Comment: And now even this link takes us to a page "This project is abandoned" ):

Comment: I believe this is the updated link to the [official Python tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html)